# Evaluating a variable using the IN() Function

Tags: sql, function, variables, sas

I'm trying to resolve a datastep variable in the in() function. I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
|Run|Sample Level|Samples Tested|
| 1 |     1      |      1-5     |
| 1 |     2      |      1-5     |
...etc
| 1 |     5      |      1-5     |
---------------------------------
| 2 |     1      |      1-4     |
| 2 |     2      |      1-4     |
```

The samples tested vary by run.  Normally the only sample levels in the dataset are the ones in the range provided by "Samples Tested".  However occasionally this is not the case, and it can get messy.  For example the last one I worked on looked like this:

```
|Run|Sample Level|Samples Tested|
| 1 |      1     |2-9, 12-35, 37-40|
```

In this case I'd want to drop all rows with sample levels that were not included in Samples Tested, which I did by manually adding the code:

```
Data Want;
set Have;
if sample_level not in (2:9, 12:35, 37:40) then delete;
run;
```

But what I want to do is have this done automatically by looking at the samples tested column.  It's easy enough to turn a "-" into a ":", but where I'm stuck is getting the `IN()` function to recognize or resolve a variable.  I would like code that looks like this: `if sample_level not in(Samples_Tested) then delete;` where samples_tested has been transformed to be something that the `IN()` function can handle.  I'm also not opposed to using `proc sql;` if anyone has a solution that they think will work.  I know you can do things like

```
Proc sql; Create table want as select * from HAVE where Sample_Level in (Select Samples_Tested from Have); Quit;
```

But the problem is that the samples tested varies by run and there could be 16 different runs.  Hopefully I've explained the challenge clearly enough.  Thanks for taking the time to read this and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does each value of RUN have only one value for Samples_Tested?

Comment: Yes.  All of run 1 will have the same Samples_Tested value.  Same with all of run 2, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the values of SAMPLES_TESTED is constant for each value of RUN you could use it to generate the selection criteria.  For example you could use a data _null_ step to write a WHERE statement to a file and then %include that code into another data step.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  file code;
  if eof then put ';';
  set have end=eof;
  by run;
  if first.run;
  if _n_=1 then put 'where ' @ ;
  else put '   or ' @ ;
  samples_tested=translate(samples_tested,':','-');
  put '(' run= 'and sample_level in (' samples_tested '))';
run;
data want;
  set have;
  %include code;
run;
```

Note: `IN` is an operator and not a function.

Comment: This is very close to working, how would I alter it if "Run" were a character variable?  The variable "Run" takes on values like 1XYZ99, 2XYZ99, 3XYZ99, etc.

Comment: Hmm.  I must have something wrong.  Here's my statement: `put '(' run_ID= :$quote. 'and sample_level in (' samples_tested'))';` and I'm getting this error message: 
" +);
       -
       22
       200
ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause."

Comment: Look at the generated code.  Just open the file or copy it to the log. Or you can add the `/source2` option to the `%include` statement to see the lines of code from the included file in the log.

Comment: There was an extra close parentheses generated by the if eof.... Fixed it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good to see SAS code ;-)

That would work with one range:

```
select * from HAVE where level in (tested);
```

For multiple ranges I would use SUBSTRING_INDEX in MySQL or just combination of SUBSTRING and INDEX to find next condition.
    select * from HAVE where level in (tested1) or level in (tested2) or level in (tested3);
Where you replace tested1 for example as substr(tested,1, index(tested,',')

I used the following to generate sample:
    create table have 
    (run int,
     level int,
     tested varchar(20));
     INSERT INTO have (run, level, tested)
    VALUES (1, 1, "3-5");
    INSERT INTO have (run, level, tested)
    VALUES (1, 3, "3-5, 12:35");
    INSERT INTO have (run, level, tested)
    VALUES (1, 20, "3-5, 12-35");

Comment: I'll give that a shot!  What if there's a different amount of conditions?  For example Run 1 had Samples Tested = "2-9, 12-35, 37-40",  Run 2 had "1,10,11,36, 41-50", and run 3 just had "1-40".  I'd need a different number of "testedX" depending on the run's requirement's, right?

Comment: Ooops, just double checked: IN function in SQL only check the list of values but not the range. The only chance is to use BETWEEN x AND y function. You can use the same logic, just careful extracting values from the tested string.

Comment: In your example Tested = "2-9, 12-35, 37-40", Run 2 had "1,10,11,36, 41-50", and run 3 just had "1-40", you need level between substr(tested,1, index(tested,'-')) and substr(tested, index(tested,'-') +1, index(tested,',')-index(tested,'-')) or level between <condition2a>[replace with correct string] and <condition2b> or level between <condition3a> and <condition3b>